# Amazon S3 Api to Bulk Copy to another bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I see that there isn't an api call to explicitly perform move but is there a way to perform bulk copy/delete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not have a move command. Instead, you would need to copy then delete.

There is no command to do bulk copy.

You can use [DeleteObjects()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3DeleteObjectsDeleteObjectsRequest.html) to delete multiple objects in one API call.

If you are willing to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), you *can* perform bulk move/copy/delete. It has commands like `aws s3 cp --recursive` and `aws s3 rm s3://bucket/path/*`